# Routing authorize.net under a specific refinery page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, authorize.net, refinerycms

I have made an app using refinery cms , everything is gud except the store . I used authorize.net for payment purpose , but the problem being the authorize.net app gets loaded at root and i want it under 'Store' . I have read about routes.rb and i am still confused as to how i will go on to do so .

These are the lines of routes.rb

match '/payments/payment', :to => 'payments#payment', :as => 'paymentspayment', :via => [:get]

match '/payments/relay_response', :to => 'payments#relay_response', :as => 'payments_relay_response', :via => [:post]

match '/payments/receipt', :to => 'payments#receipt', :as => 'payments_receipt', :via => [:get]

root :to => 'payments#payment'

I have loaded Store as an extendable engine for refinery cms .
I am a rails newbie , so plz bear with me . Any links on how to achieve so would also be very helpful .

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah , my bad . To anyone who finds himself in a similar situation . Add the store engine and create an order from refinery admin side on the extended engine page . Authorize.net picks up the page on method call and the submit query makes it easier to redirect it directly to their payment page .